# Microsoft Graph API: Filter email messages within a time range

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I do not see support for filtering list of emails from the Graph API to a date range? Like it'd be nice to have something that supports filtering between a start date and an end date for the receivedDateTime field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try $filter query:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=(receivedDateTime ge 2017-03-13T04:14:08Z) and (receivedDateTime le 2017-04-12T05:15:08Z)
```

Comment: Thanks Nan Yu - I had trouble finding accurate documentation for what are the supported operations in the filter and search operations? Like I have a variety of cases where I might need to do things like search for mails with sender not in list type of queries. Any pointers of good source for such cases?

Comment: @Keshi , seems no such document , you could refer to [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-supported-queries-filters-and-paging-options) , that is azure ad graph api related , but you could try that .

Comment: Yu - thanks - Ya - I remember reading it but I dont see support for 'in list' queries. Is this in the roadmap?